# Azure Eclipse installing Scala IDE

Tags: java, eclipse, scala, azure

On Windows 10: I am attempting to setup Eclipse Neon to work with Azure.  When I attempt to install Scala I get the following message:

The following solutions are not compatible with this version of eclipse.
Scala IDE

Version: Neon.2 Release (4.6.2)
Build id: 20161208-0600

I can create Java packages, I can't see why it won't let me.  This is the C/C++ developers version of eclipse with the Java Development tools added.

I have the same situation on a linux machine, it is running Eclipse Oxygen.3A

I don't want to upgrade the Windows version unless I have to.

Added:

When I go to Eclipse marketplace ad search for Scala I get Scalastyle 0.9.0 and it is installed.

Comment: Are you installing Eclipse IDE from Eclipse Marketplace?

Comment: Yes, I am trying to follow the azure installation procedure.

Answer (score 0):

If you can not directly install Scala IDE from Eclipse Marketplace, the workaround way is to download a zipfile wrapped [the pre-stable one from Scala IDE offical website](http://scala-ide.org/download/prev-stable.html) to follow the below steps to install it.

[image]

And here is the installation steps from a zipfile.

1. Help -> Install New Software
2. Click on "Add"
3. Click on "Archive"
4. Select the *.zip file
5. The "Location:" text field fo the "Add Site" dialog shows 
   "jar:file:/base-20170609-1342.zip!/"